# Convert a histogram plot from a Pandas dataframe to a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, scatter

I have a histogram:

```
# Lets load a dataset of house prices in Boston. 
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
#sklearn gives you the data as a dictionary, so 
diabetes = load_diabetes(as_frame=True)
data = diabetes['frame']
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
bmi_hist = plt.hist(data['bmi'], density=False)
bmi_hist = plt.ylabel("Frequency")
bmi_hist = plt.xlabel("Normalized BMI")
bp_hist = plt.hist(data['bp'], density=False)
bp_hist = plt.ylabel("Frequency")
bp_hist = plt.xlabel("Normalized BP")
```

This is a histogram for two of the columns in the frame above.
I want to compare these two in a scatter graph. My attempts haven't been quite successful as I know I need an X and a Y to plot.
I thought I would use the same axis as the histogram:

```
y_bmi = data['bmi'].value_counts() # frequency
x_bmi = data['bmi'] # normalized value
ax1 = df.plot.scatter(x = x_bmi, y= y_bmi, c='DarkBlue')
```

But this can only be used on the 'dataframe' so do I have to repeat the values of bmi column into a new dataframe? or is there a simpler method?

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**
Many Thanks.

Comment: `data[['bmi', 'bp']].plot(kind='hist', ec='k', alpha=0.5, figsize=(5, 4))` is an easier implementation for you histogram.

Comment: Something like `import seaborn as sns` and `sns.lmplot(data=data, x='bmi', y='bp', hue='sex')` is a better way to compare the relationship between `'bmi'` and `'bp'`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easier implementation for you histogram:

```
data[['bmi', 'bp']].plot(kind='hist', ec='k', alpha=0.5, figsize=(5, 4))
```